# How can I recover from deleting the /usr/share/themes directory?

Tags: themes, files, directory, data-recovery, system

I deleted the  `/usr/share/themes` directory, how can I recover it?
Is there any way to check if there is any missing file/directory in /Computer directory?
This was a bad try to change GIMP and Inkscape themes ("gtkrc" file).
I changed all "gtkrc" files that I found in the system (stupid me...) and now my windows and apps are distorted =(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run `dpkg -S /usr/share/themes` to see what packages you have installed that install files into that directory. Then, run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall packages`, replacing `packages` with the list of packages returned by the previous command.