# Overwritten /usr/share/bin. Am I doomed?

Tags: filesystem, 18.10, cp, binary

I just managed to overwrite `/usr/share/bin`

and it doesn't seem like it's possible to undo.

I did this as a root user.

Am I doomed?

Comment: No, not doomed. You can easily backup and reinstall.

Comment: Might not be a bad idea.

Comment: If it helps, I have a pretty clean installation of 18.04 and it does not have a `/usr/share/bin` folder at all.  I think you will be fine.

Comment: That is reassuring. I was only worried because I'm running as root.

Comment: Hey, doesn't hurt to ask.  =)

Comment: It happened to me some time ago to overried `/usr/local/bin`. Still not fatal. Most of the stuff that was there were "ruby gems" (e.g. `fpm`). Anyway they are just user applications so you can continue using your system and when you see a weird error about not finding `/usr/.../bin/application` you know that you have to reinstall it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover from deleting the /usr/share/themes directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493637/how-can-i-recover-from-deleting-the-usr-share-themes-directory)

Comment: This question has far higher scores than the the "duplicated" question. The answer is also easier to understand.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Not doomed at all.**

Nothing critical in a Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server install uses `/usr/share/bin`.

Run `dpkg -S /usr/share/bin` to list your installed packages that use dir. Those packages, if any, should be reinstalled.

If the reply is `no path found matching pattern`, then you indeed have nothing installed that uses the dir.

Comment: It just sends me an error message `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/share/bin`

Comment: That would indicate that you have no installed packages referring to the directory.

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't look like a standard location.

Comment: @Ruslan: I've seen it in the standards before (but it might not be in the current ones); since the only plausible things that could live there are scripts and jitted binaries being empty/non-extant is plausible.

Comment: @Joshua given that `/usr` hierarchy is not normally writable, I doubt there could be jitted binaries. I'd rather expect them in `/var/cache` or somewhere else under the `/var` tree.

Comment: @Ruslan: jitted binaries means binaries that run via a jitter, not binaries that are the output of a jitter.